# PDF viewer - How to make pdf icons visible always in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, pdf, pdf-viewer

In my application I'm displaying a pdf in `<object>` tag like this,

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQNCiX15Pb8DQoNCjkgMCBvYmoNCj....
```

The default icons (print, save zoom) buttons. These icons are visible only on mouse hover. Is there any way to make these icons visible all the time. (Consider only IE as the browser)

[image]

Comment: Can we see more of the code?

Comment: There is no more code. The base 64 encoded string is displayed in object tag as shown in the question. and rest everything browser takes care.